# Bootstrap Grid Layout - Move Block up at Mobile View

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I have a regular Grid which moves everything correctly on the place at Mobile and Desktop View.

But I want to move my Title over the Image at Mobile View. Anybody idea how can I nest the Blocks?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-8"><h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-sm-12">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</div>
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/d9WbmWJCGv

Comment: Crap! it looks like I overwrote your Bootply!! I didn't know that was possible?!? Seems like it shouldn't be, and that I should have to fork to save, but either way, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a little `pull-left` and `pull-right`, and `img-responsive` helps avoid image overlap.

[**Bootply Example**](http://www.bootply.com/dn7gx2xVWA)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 pull-right">
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum...</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="image img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 pull-right">
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the Bootply, I also added .red, .blue, .green to the css sheet to help see what's going on. just need to be un-x'd.

Comment: Also, since Bootstrap 3 is mobile-first, when moving columns around, it's best to order your divs how you want them on mobile, and then use push/pull (as well as col-push/pull) to put them where you want for desktop, as opposed to the other way around.